# Copy table from Excel into Outlook and send to multiple people in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to copy a table (with all formatting intact) from Excel into an email and then send separate emails to people on a list in Excel. [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/) has two sets of code on his website.

One does the first part, while the other does the second part. How can I combine these?

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail5.htm

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                        "your account up to date"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please paste any code you are using into the question itself.  Content of third-party websites could change at any time, which would render your question meaningless if you just include links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace the following

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

With this

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
```

Then change this

```
        .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
              & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                "your account up to date"
```

With this

```
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but this does not work. I get compile error 'label not defined' on this part "On Error GoTo cleanup"